# Is it possible to find files or directories in a Git repository while physically on the remote?

Tags: git

We have just shy of 200 git repositories on a server, and I'd like to search them for files or directories, e.g.

`git ls-files | grep foobar`

I'd be looking to do this directly from the server these live on (via SSH).

Going to the directory on the remote and running most git commands doesn't result in anything.

Comment: `git ls-files` reads the index and work-tree. Server repositories are usually bare, and hence have no work-tree. (They still have an index, for historical reasons, but their index contents tend to be useless.) Perhaps you want `git ls-tree -r <commit-specifier>`? (perhaps also with `--name-only`)

Comment: Which server are you using? If you are using Gitlab for instance, I would recommended going through de API.

Comment: Besides that, you might want to try Source Graph ( https://about.sourcegraph.com/blog/introducing-sourcegraph-server-2-4/) which is a tool to search across multiple git repositories. The downside is that it requires some setup effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to torek for the heads-up about `git ls-tree`, which does work while on the server, I was able to write a quick and dirty bash script to go through all of the repositories on the remote:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do
    cd $f;
    echo $f;
    echo;
    git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep foobar;
    cd -;
done;
```

This showed me which repositories contained a file or directory called foobar.